# adjust ToolStripMenuItem dropdown size

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, toolstrip

Hello I've got a loop that adds some drop down items to a Tool Strip:

`usersToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(ss);`

However this list is going to be long. Is there any way to confine the size of the drop down box (which currently takes up the height of the screen)?

On another note, I've noticed it doesn't support scrolling, is that doable?

Comment: It is already confined, it ran out of screen.  Click the little triangle at the bottom to scroll.  Usability demands you start using sub-menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possible.

Hans Passant:

It is already confined, it ran out of screen. Click the little triangle at the bottom to scroll. Usability demands you start using sub-menus.